# How can execute same test steps for web application bilingual (English and Arabic ) using cucumber and selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I want to automate some set of test steps for both interface (English & Arabic)
like 
login
select product
add to cart

so I create feature file in cucumber and wrote all test scenario with testing steps and working fine for English site URL

**Now I want to execute same testing steps for the same site but for Arabic interface**
any solution please

Comment: you need to make cucumber steps with variables for different languages and use regex in step definitions

Comment: can you give me refrence example because right now Feature: Verify sample tests for home and login screen 

Background: Open home page and change language
 Given Open chrome and open site Demosite
 When User changes language in welcome screen
 And  User clicks on subscribe now button

Answer (score 0):

Using cucumber expressions is a basic feature of this framework.
You can parameterize your step like:
`Open home page and change language to English`
the same step could be `Open home page and change language to Arabic`
your step definition could be like:

```
@When("^Open home page and change language to (.+)$")
public void changeLang(String language) {
...
}
```

With method like this you will be able to pass your *languages* into `changeLang` method and do some action with it in accordance with language (you can do some `if`s or `switch` etc). You can read [more](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/) about expression types and useful cases.

Comment: agree with your comments,

Comment: agree with your comments

Actually I am working with Background(Because i need some testing steps which always execute before each test scenario)
in background i cant make variable.

1-before each test scenario site changed into english language and then like this 5 test scenario successfully completed.

question ?
How execute same test scenario for same site in arabic.